# Login Failed for User when executing packages with DTExec in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS package deployed in server ***A***. The packages pulls data from database in server ***B***. However, I only have one service account which has access to both.

When I execute the package in SSMS opened with service account ***'SC1'*** credentials the package fails with `"Login failed for user"` error. When I looked at the Execution results in SSISDB I see that a different account is being used to execute the package '***SC2***'

How can I execute the package using stored procedure by providing ***SC1*** as the user to be used to execute??

Answer (score 0):

You can try using /User, /Password commands to make sure your package executes with required user. for more details refer https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810%28v=sql.105%29.aspx '/SQ[L] package_path' parameter

Comment: No.... /User only works with /SQ parameter. But I'm executing packages deployed in SSIS DB using /ISServer and this does not allow us to use this paramater